# Is there any method to doing Aspect-Oriented Programming in Go language

Tags: go, aop

I'm trying to use Aspect-Oriented Programming in go program, For example, log the info in service, Without intrusion to my function codes, But I find there is not a method to do.

Comment: AOP as it's commonly used only really applies to object-oriented languages, which Go is not. You can achieve the same goals with more functional patterns using closures and function values, e.g. wrapping a function in another function.

Answer (score 9):

Go generally leans towards design and code low on "magic", preferring explicitness. Middleware is a common design pattern that provides a lot of what folks do with AOP, like the simple example you mention - when your server code is set up properly, you can register middleware that will automatically log things, etc. There are some code samples for middleware on the [Go Web Examples site](https://gowebexamples.com/basic-middleware/), and googling will uncover much more. [This tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/simple-http-middleware-with-go-79a4ad62889b) talks about logging middleware, etc.

Comment: Almost looks like a link only answer to a question asking for libraries, tools, ...

Comment: @GhostCat: I wouldn't call it a link-only answer, the links are just examples of what you can find online. I believe the main value of this answer is to provide the right terminology the OP was looking for - in my experience when people look for AOP in Go they usually mean middleware

Comment: Not arguing here, just sayin... ;-)