# How to use/implement aspect orientation in Go?

Tags: java, go, annotations, aspect

I'd like to monitor arbitrary method calls and I am interested in 3 metrics of the method call:

1. total time
2. total number of requests
3. total number of errors

In Java, I can define an annotation which inject the metrics initialization and calculating before and after the method call. For instance:

```
@Monitor
public void foo() {
   // do some stuff...
}
```

And this `@Monitor` annotation will inject some codes before and after the `foo` to generate the metrics for it.

Is there a similar way to achieve this in Go?

Comment: Aspect-Oriented Programming framework for Go:  [this](https://github.com/AkihiroSuda/aspectgo) and [this](https://github.com/gogap/aop), SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682669/is-there-any-method-to-doing-aspect-oriented-programming-in-go-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Aspect-Oriented Programming framework for Go](https://github.com/AkihiroSuda/aspectgo) and [this](https://github.com/gogap/aop).

And see [How to write benchmarks in Go - Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go)

---

You may use a proxy function to do this:

```
total time: 1.002061047s
total number of requests: 10
number of errors: 0
```

Proxy function:

```
func (p *metrics) proxy(user func() error) func() error {
    return func() error {
        p.nCalls++
        t0 := time.Now()
        err := user()
        t := time.Since(t0)
        // p.d = append(p.d, t)
        p.total += t
        if err != nil {
            p.nErrs++
        }
        return err
    }
}
```

All:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := new(metrics)
    f := m.proxy(user)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        f()
    }
    m.show()
}
func user() error {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    return nil
}

type metrics struct {
    nCalls, nErrs int
    total         time.Duration
    // d []time.Duration
}

func (p *metrics) proxy(user func() error) func() error {
    return func() error {
        p.nCalls++
        t0 := time.Now()
        err := user()
        t := time.Since(t0)
        // p.d = append(p.d, t)
        p.total += t
        if err != nil {
            p.nErrs++
        }
        return err
    }
}
func (p *metrics) show() {
    fmt.Println("total time:", p.total)
    fmt.Println("total number of requests:", p.nCalls)
    fmt.Println("number of errors:", p.nErrs)
}
```

Comment: This requires all the methods have the same signature.

Comment: No, at least two options: 1: For example to call this user function `func user2(i int) error {...}` you may use `f := m.proxy(func() error { return user2(10) })` or 2: write new proxy

Comment: What you need is Go benchmarks: see [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a similar way to achieve this in Go[...]?

No.

You have to write a wrapper which manually intercepts input, analyses output and measures time.

(Please note that the name if the language is simply "Go". golang.org is the website.)